# Sharepoint item in list is deleted but notification triggers still continuos

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, approval-process, email-notification

I have a flow which requires multiple approvals with email notifications. This starts when an item is created in a sharepoint list. How do I stop the flow if an item created needs to be deleted? Tried to delete an item but even I had it deleted, the flow still sends out email notification to the approver on the deleted item.

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't know the specific details of the flow, according to your description, I suggest you go to the power automate to find your flow first, and turn it off. Then edit your flow and add a conditional judgment. If the item does not exist, it will end directly. Finally, run the flow again.

Comment: Good day, Amy.

Hope you are well.

Greatly appreciate your inputs. Where do I insert the conditional judgement in my flow? What I need to happen is to stop the email reminder trigger if an item is deleted. What currently happens is that once an item is created, it keeps on running the whole flow even if the item has been deleted.

Thanks for the help.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/puZcJ.png

Comment: Before sending the email application, add a judgment, if the ID of the item is equal to null, it will end, otherwise, go to the next process.